# Labelling cluster features in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, clustering

I'm trying to label a vector layer with clustered points in OpenLayers. When the feature is clustered I want to show the value of an attribute of all the features included in the cluster.
I've tried to define my label as follows:

```
label: function(feature){if (feature.cluster) {
                 for(i=0;i<feature.cluster.length;i++)
                {label_array += feature.cluster[i].attributes.yacimiento;
                 label = label_array.toString();
                }
            }
          else{label=feature.attributes.yacimiento;}
      return label;
      }
```

... and the vector layer just doesn't work

BUT, if I do the same with

```
label_array = feature.cluster[i].attributes.yacimiento;
```

it works prefectly displaying only the last item of the cluster

I don't understand what's going on (I might be missing something obvious, for I have no programming skills)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution, in case anybody is interested:

```
label: function(feature){if (feature.cluster) {
        var label_array = new Array();
            for(i=0;i<feature.cluster.length;i++)
            { 
            label_array.push(feature.cluster[i].attributes.yacimiento);
            label = label_array.join("\n");
            }
        }
  else{label=feature.attributes.yacimiento;}
  return label;
  }
```